# Functions with very big numbers in C++

Tags: c++, function, long-integer

I am fairly new to C++, and have been trying to write a program to process very big input numbers (7e+11 ish). It works fine with little numbers, but not with these big ones. I realise this is because very big numbers won't fit in an int, but when I try other types like __int64, long long int, unsigned long long int and uint64_t the function "nextsmallestfactor" doesn't work (it normally outputs 0 and so triggers an error when dividing by a, the output). What should I use then? This code is supposed to take a big number, repeatedly divide it by the smallest number that divides into it each time, and output a, the highest prime factor, at the end.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int numberToFactorise = 700000000000;
int nextsmallestfactor(int numbertofactorise){
    for (int factor = 2; factor < numbertofactorise; factor++){
    if (numbertofactorise%factor == 0){
        return factor;
    }
}
}
int main(){
    int quotient = numberToFactorise;
    int a=1;
    while (quotient > 1){
        a = nextsmallestfactor(quotient);
        quotient = quotient / a;
    };
    cout << a;
cout << endl;
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

}

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: The maximum size of an int is 2,147,483,647

Comment: Not all code paths in nextsmallestfactor() return a value... But if you change you condition to `factor <= numbertofactorise` then you should be good, since x%x == 0 for all values, the if statement must be true for one iteration

Comment: You have to use bigger `int` type, like `int64_t`. As for "my function does not work"... well, you have to figure out what does not work. Whatever problems your function has, they have nothing to do with the fact that you used `int64_t`.

Comment: I don't see how the code posted should ever work, independent of input magnitude.  Eventually you will end up with `quotient` as a prime number, and `nextsmallestfactor` will return an undefined value, unlikely to be the same value as the correct answer which is `quotient` itself.

Comment: BTW, this code is very inefficient since you can stop at `sqrt( numbertofactorise )`. If you reach the square root of the number and still haven't found a factor, then `numbertofactorise` is prime and that value can be returned.

Comment: I don't know why some people has downvoted this question but someone should upvoting because this question it's licit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that if you give your function a prime number, then the code never actually returns a value and therefore produces undefined behavior. Lets write out the iterations of the loop when we input a prime number:

```
nextsmallestfactor( 5 ):

      factor  |  numbertofactorise % factor
       ----------------------------
        2     |   5%2 = 1
        3     |   5%3 = 2
        4     |   5%4 = 1 

 END (no return)
```

If you change the conditional to check for factor up to **and including** the `numbertofactorize` then it will do:

```
nextsmallestfactor( 5 ):

      factor  |  numbertofactorise % factor
       ----------------------------
        2     |   5%2 = 1
        3     |   5%3 = 2
        4     |   5%4 = 1 
        5     |   5%5 = 0  ---> return 5;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your lovely ASCII art helped me to understand and resolve the problem - I just needed to change int to int64_t and factor < numbertofactorise to factor <= numbertofactorise

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write some C++ code able to deal with huge numbers (with all their digits) you need [bignums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bignum). Then I suggest you to use some existing bignum library like [GMPLIB](http://gmplib.org/); you''ll be able to compute e.g. factorial of 1000 with all its digits.

Don't try to reinvent your own bignum library; since the complex underlying algorithms (which are more efficient than naive ones) are quite difficult to understand (and to re-invent).

Some languages and implementations (e.g. [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) for Common Lisp) have builtin bignums.